# Does Lambert W function works for vector valued equations

Tags: linear-algebra, lambert-w

I faced an algebraic equation that I'm not sure if there's a closed form solution for it.
The equation is
$$
\bf{A} Z + b \exp(\mu + 1^T.Z) = 0
$$
Where $\bf{A}$ is a diagonal matrix and $\bf{b}, 1, Z$ are vectors.

I know that when $z$ is scalar, there's a closed-form solution for such equations.
$$
z = -W\left(a b \exp(\mu)\right)
$$
Where $W$ is the Lambert-W function.

Does such solution exist when $\bf{Z}$ is a vector? Or I should use numerical methods to find the roots of this system?

Comment: You can probably extend its domain via its series expansion and other representations.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Could you elaborate on this, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\bf A$ is invertible, multiply your equation by ${\bf A}^{-1}$ on the left to see that
${\bf Z} = z {\bf A}^{-1} {\bf b}$ where
$$ z = - \exp(\mu + {\bf 1}^T {\bf Z}) = -\exp(\mu + z \; {\bf 1}^T{\bf A}^{-1} {\bf b})$$
This is now a scalar equation where you can use LambertW.

Comment: It's a beautiful answer, thanks!